# SyntaxError: Unexpected token * with coffeescript when run on codeship

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, codeship

I'm having trouble getting my mocha tests to work on Codeship. These are working locally. I've deleted the repo and ran `npm install`. Still worked locally but not remote.

I'm not sure if this is a coffeescript compile error when codeship tries to run the tests, but there isn't too much information about their platform's support for the language.

Am I missing something I have to add to my codeship test environment? Not sure why the code would be fine local but break everything in codeship.

When run locally:

```
Debugger listening on port 5858


  Verify codeship works
    Ok should eql Ok
      ✓ should not post to the public channel


  1 passing (487ms)
```

Codeship test result:

```
debugger listening on port 5858

/home/rof/src/github.com/sprk-platform/tracker-bot/test/conversation_test.coffee:27
return function*() {
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.loadFile (/home/rof/.nvm/v0.10.45/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:16:19)
at Module.load (/home/rof/.nvm/v0.10.45/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at /home/rof/.nvm/v0.10.45/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:27
at Array.forEach (native)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/rof/.nvm/v0.10.45/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:216:14)
at Mocha.run (/home/rof/.nvm/v0.10.45/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:468:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rof/.nvm/v0.10.45/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:403:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:945:3
```

Test file:

```
expect = require('chai').expect
should = require('chai').should

Helper      = require('hubot-test-helper')
helper = new Helper('../scripts/events.coffee')

co          = require('co')
Promise     = require('bluebird')

describe 'Verify codeship works', ->

  beforeEach ->
    @room = helper.createRoom()
    return

  describe 'Ok should eql Ok', ->

    beforeEach ->
      co =>
        yield @room.user.say '1', 'hello'
        return

    it 'should not post to the public channel', ->
      expect("ok").to.eql "ok"
      return
```

Events.coffee:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.on 'some-event', (some, data) ->
    robot.messageRoom 'room1', "got event with #{some} #{data}"

  robot.respond /send event$/i, (msg) ->
    robot.emit 'response-event',
      content: 'hello'
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "hubot": "latest",
    "hubot-brain-inspect": "0.0.1",
    "hubot-conversation": "^1.0.3",
    "hubot-diagnostics": "0.0.1",
    "hubot-env": "0.0.2",
    "hubot-google-images": "^0.2.6",
    "hubot-google-translate": "^0.2.0",
    "hubot-help": "^0.1.3",
    "hubot-heroku-keepalive": "^1.0.2",
    "hubot-maps": "0.0.2",
    "hubot-pugme": "^0.1.0",
    "hubot-redis-brain": "0.0.3",
    "hubot-rules": "^0.1.1",
    "hubot-scripts": "^2.16.2",
    "hubot-shipit": "^0.2.0",
    "knwl.js": "^1.0.2",
    "nlp_compromise": "^3.0.8",
    "qs": "^6.1.0",
    "coffee-script": "latest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/mocha --opts ./test/mocha.opts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.3.5",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "co": "4.6.0",
    "coffee-errors": "^0.8.6",
    "hubot-mock-adapter": "^1.0.0",
    "hubot-test-helper": "latest",
    "mocha": "latest",
    "mocha-retry": "^0.1.0",
    "mockery": "latest",
    "sinon": "latest",
    "sinon-chai": "latest"
  }
}
```

And the mocha.opts:

```
--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
--ui tdd
--reporter spec
--recursive
--debug
--inline-diffs
```

Also tried adding `--require coffee-script`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was an inconsistent node version. Local was `5.6.0` and package.json required `0.10.x`. The thing that was breaking the tests was `yield`, which is part of ECMA6.